# Robots.txt deny, for a #! URL

Tags: javascript, robots.txt

I am trying to add a deny rule to a robots.txt file, to deny access to a single page.

The website URLs work as follows:

- http://example.com/#!/homepage
- http://example.com/#!/about-us
- http://example.com/#!/super-secret

Javascript then swaps out the DIV that is displayed, based on the URL.

How would I request a search engine spider not list the following:

- http://example.com/#!/super-secret
- http://example.com/index.php#!/super-secret

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if search engines can scrape such URLs at all. But if they can, there's no reason to believe why adding them as such in the robots.txt deny list wouldn't work.

Comment: i didn't think the stuff to the right of "#" went over the wire at all, so to an external server, it likely looks like just the prototcol, domain and path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this multiple ways, but here are the two simplest.

You have to exclude the URLs that Googlebot is going to fetch, which isn't the AJAX hashbang values, but the instead the translated `?_escaped_fragment_=key=value`

In your robots.txt file specify:

```
Disallow: /?_escaped_fragment_=/super-secret
Disallow: /index.php?_escaped_fragment_=/super-secret
```

When in doubt, you should always use the Google Webmaster Tool » "[Fetch As Googlebot](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587)".

If the page has already been indexed by Googlebot, using a robots.txt file won't remove it from the index. You'll either have to use the Google Webmaster Tools URL removal tool after you apply the robots.txt, or instead you can add a [`noindex` command to the page](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag) via a `<meta>` tag or `X-Robots-Tag` in the HTTP Headers.

It would look something like:

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
```

or

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

Comment: At this point, Google has deprecated the AJAX crawling scheme that it once supported.  It doesn't convert hash  bangs into `?_escaped_fragment_=` anymore when it crawls.

Comment: Agreed. @StephenOstermiller is correct. The AJAX crawling scheme was officially unsupported by Google in October of 2018. ref: https://www.seroundtable.com/google-fully-deprecated-ajax-crawling-scheme-26530.html

Answer (score 3):

You can't (per se). Search engines wouldn't run JavaScript anyway, so will generally ignore the fragment identifier. You can only deny the URLs that would be requested from the server (which are without fragment identifiers).

Google will map hashbangs onto [different URIs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) and you can figure out what those are (and you should have done already because that is the point of using hash bangs) and put *them* in robots.txt.

Hash bangs, however, are [problematic at best](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs), so I'd scrap them in favour of using [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) which allows you to use sane URIs.

Comment: actually, bing and google both run javascript in thier crawler. It's not the full set, and details are slender, but js-injected links have been found on both engines...

Comment: Hmmm, so it's not just as simple as "Disallow: #!/super-secret" and "Disallow: index.php#!/super-secret". Delightful. Lol