# #! url showing up at the top of my search results

Tags: ajax, seo

[image]

We are just getting started with SEO/Ajax so hoping someone can help us figure this out - One of the #! urls is showing up as the first organic result for our startup nurturelist.com. Although this link technically works, we would 1) not like to have any #! urls show up in search results because they look weird and we have non #! versions 2) the second organic result in the image is the one that we'd actually like to appear at the top.

Thanks very much on any thoughts on how we can make this happen...

Answer (score 0):

Do you just simply not want the #! to show up in search results? Simply make a `robots.txt` in your root directory (in most cases the `public_html` directory) and add these lines to it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /\#!/
```

This prevents Google from indexing all pages under the `/#!/` subdirectory.

However:

> If the page has already been indexed by Googlebot, using a robots.txt
>   file won't remove it from the index. You'll either have to use the
>   Google Webmaster Tools URL removal tool after you apply the
>   robots.txt, or instead you can add a noindex command to the page via a
>    tag or X-Robots-Tag in the HTTP Headers.

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987717/robots-txt-deny-for-a-url))

[Here is a link to the Google Webmaster Tools URL Removal Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals)

So add this to pages you don't want indexed:

`<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />`

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry I did not respond until now but I'm going to give this a try and see what happens.