# Google Search: get rid of Hash-Bang indexed pages

Tags: google-search, hashbang

How can I get rid of Hash-Bang indexed pages on Google Search?

In about 2010 I have made a website that used Ajax-loaded content and the use of Hash-Bang in the URLs.

eg: `http://example.com/#!98_153`

That was the recommended way to get all content crawled by Google in 2010.

12 years later in 2022 a complete relaunch of this Website was done.
URLs look (user read-friendly) like
`http://example.com/publications/my-first-book`
now.

There is a `robots.txt` file.
And there is a `sitemap.xml`.
Also there is a Google tag manager on the new site.

Google is still showing those old URLs with Hash-Bangs.

How do I get rid of those Hash-Bangs-Urls?

`robots.txt`:

```
Sitemap: https://www.my-websitexxxxx.example/sitemap.xml
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /dev/
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /Security/
Disallow: /#!*
Disallow: /print/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The hash and everything after it is client-side only.  It isn't part of the URL that is sent to the server. Browsers never send the hash fragment to the server.  Crawlers never send the hash fragment to the server.  Therefore:

- [robots.txt rules with `#` in them are not effective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987717/robots-txt-deny-for-a-url)
- You can't use server side redirects or rewrites with them.

The only thing that you can do is redirect those URLs with JavaScript.

```js
if (location.hash == '#!98_153') location.href = 'http://example.com/publications/my-first-book'
```

Googlebot now runs JavaScript as part of its crawling process. Once you have the JavaScript redirects in place, Googlebot will eventually find them and honor them. Your hash bang URLs will no longer be indexed.

Comment: There are a lot of those hash-bangs. the single hash-bang has no logical connect to the actual database. what i already have is: if (location.href.indexOf("#!") != -1) {
   window.location.href = "/404";
    }         --------- but all this is not satisfying.

Comment: You are saying that right now you are redirecting all hash bangs to a 404?  Googlebot should pick up on that, but it could take up to a year before Google re-crawls and re-renders all your URLs.

Comment: If you could create a map of those hash bangs to their new URLs and do a more specific redirect, any SEO value from your old URLs would be more likely to be preserved.

Comment: If you want to speed up the process, you could create a temporary XML sitemap that has all your old hash bang URLs in it and ask Googlebot to come crawl it by submitting the sitemap to Google Search Console.